# How to share a word document with a schema attached?

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, xml-schema-validation

On my own machine (Word 2007) I have successfully added a custom XML part to a .docx file, associated the custom XML nodes with a custom .xsd schema and I now have editable custom XML nodes - great.

The problem is, when I send the .docx file to my colleagues (Word 2010 & Mac Word 2004) - there is nothing to be found in the Developer Tab > Structure panel, as there was for me. What I did see though, when I opened up the schema settings, was " schema unavailable" next to the name of the schema I'd originally attached. I also tried to associate a different schema from a shared location - but again it worked for me but not my colleagues.

The custom XML parts did show up in another colleagues' Word 2007 (same as mine), so I was guessing it either needs permanent association, kind of like embedding images, or custom XMl is not compatible across any versions of modern Word.

How can I use custom XML parts and a custom schema, and have them persist across users with Word 2003, 2007 and 2010 (forget Mac 2004, I was just checking)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.osnews.com/story/21983/Judge_Rules_Microsoft_Infringes_XML_Patent

Awesome, Microsoft broke the law, so the functionality is partially/not implemented across different versions.